# Track application startup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Is it possible to check with BroadcastReceiver which application was running on the device? Read different sources it says that you can not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Broadcast for when an app is launched on the device.

At best, you can keep polling the recent apps to make a list of the apps the user is using. On older versions of Android, you could try parsing the Logcat output from ActivityManager.